S3 presigned post URL with AWS SDK
I am working on a generating a S3 presigned post URL with AWS SDK with java. This is my java function:

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PresignedPost;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PresignedPostRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedPostRequest;

public String getPreSignedUrlWithChecksum(String filename, MediaType mediaType, String checksum) {
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(filename)) {
                return null;
            }

            long expiry = configUtils.getS3UrlExpiry() * 60 * 1000;

            Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiry);

            PresignedPostRequest presignedPostRequest = new PresignedPostRequest()
                    .withBucket(configUtils.getS3Bucket())
                    .withKey(filename)
                    .withExpiration(expiration);

            Map<String, String> formFields = new HashMap<>();
            formFields.put("x-amz-checksum-algorithm", "CRC32");
            formFields.put("x-amz-checksum-crc32", checksum);

            presignedPostRequest.setFormFields(formFields);

            PresignedPost presignedPost = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedPost(presignedPostRequest);

            // Extract fields from the presigned POST
            Map<String, String> responseFields = presignedPost.getFields();

            // Construct the JSON response
            String jsonResponse = String.format(
                    "{\"url\":\"%s\", \"fields\": {\"x-amz-checksum-algorithm\":\"CRC32\", \"x-amz-checksum-crc32\":\"%s\", \"key\":\"%s\", \"x-amz-algorithm\":\"%s\", \"x-amz-credential\":\"%s\", \"x-amz-date\":\"%s\", \"policy\":\"%s\", \"x-amz-signature\":\"%s\"}}",
                    presignedPost.getUrl().toString(),
                    checksum,
                    responseFields.get("key"),
                    responseFields.get("x-amz-algorithm"),
                    responseFields.get("x-amz-credential"),
                    responseFields.get("x-amz-date"),
                    responseFields.get("policy"),
                    responseFields.get("x-amz-signature")
            );

            return jsonResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error generating pre-signed POST URL with checksum - {}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

But the imports are not being recognised by my compiler. Here is my pom.xml:
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <aws.sdk.version>1.12.500</aws.sdk.version>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
type here

What am I doing wrong here. Is the aws sdk version incompatible with presignedPostRequest?
I want to generate a presigned S3 URL with CRC32 checksum included as form field.
What am I doing wrong here. Is the aws sdk version incompatible with presignedPostRequest? Although, I tried it with different versions, but it didn't work.
I want to generate a presigned S3 URL with CRC32 checksum included as form field.
Is there any other way?
